# Getting the sticky menu bar to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html document, where I tried to make the top bar of my website (navbar containing navopener, which opens a menu on the left side) sticky so that it always stays at the top when scrolling. However, the opposite effect is true: When scrolling, it just disappears. How can I fix this? Note: I am not very good with Javascript/Css/Html.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css">
    <script src="../javascript/sidenav.js"></script>
    <title>Apple</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="sidenav_left" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closer" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="../index.html">Zurück zur Startseite</a>
  <a href="google.html">Google</a>
  <a href="facebook.html">Facebook</a>
  <a href="amazon.html">Amazon</a>
  <a href="apple.html">Apple</a>
  <a href="kommentar.html">Kommentar</a>
  <a href="abwaegung.html">Wer ist mächtiger?</a>
  <a href="urteil.html">Urteil</a>
  <a href="quellen.html">Quellen</a>
  <a href="quellenreflexion.html">Quellenreflexion</a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
  <span class="navOpener" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776;</span>
   </div>

  <div id="main">
  <img class="complogo" src="../img/apple.jpg" alt="Apple-Logo">
  <div class="textbox">
<h1>Apple</h1>
<p>Apple Inc. ist ein US-amerikanisches Technologieunternehmen mit Sitz in Cupertino. Das Unternehmen entwickelt und vertreibt Computer, Smartphones, Unterhaltungselektronik sowie Betriebssysteme und Anwendungssoftware. Es zählt außerdem zu den ersten Herstellern von Personal Computern.</p>
<p>Apple wurde 1976 von Steve Wozniak, Steve Jobs und Ron Wayne in einer Garage gegründet. Das Startkapital Apples lag bei 1300 US-Dollar. Als Idee zur Firmengründung diente der Computer von Steve Wozniak als Basis und war gleichzeitig das erste Produkt der Firma. Steve Jobs galt als die treibende Kraft hinter der Unternehmensgründung. Wozniak musste angeblich erst überzeugt werden, die Spezifikationen des Apple I nicht kostenlos an seinen damaligen Arbeitgeber zu übergeben. Der heute weitgehend in Vergessen geratene Ronald Wayne zog sich schon nach weniger als zwei Wochen aus dem Unternehmen zurück und ließ sich von seinen nur 21 und 25 Jahre alten Kollegen für 800 Dollar ausbezahlen. 1985 verließ Steve Jobs aufgrund von immer häufiger auftretenden Konflikten das Unternehmen, um noch im gleichen Jahr eine Konkurrenzfirma namens NeXT Inc. zu gründen. Nach der Krise 1993-1994 kaufte Apple die Firma von Steve Jobs für 404 Millionen Dollar auf. Somit kam Steve Jobs 1997 zurück ins Unternehmen und krempelte es als neuer CEO sehr schnell um. Apples Situation hatte sich in den zehn Jahren seit Jobs' Rückkehr enorm verbessert, das Unternehmen wirft lukrative Gewinne ab und ist dabei, sich ein Lifestyle-Image mitsamt großer Fan-Basis aufzubauen.</p>
<p>Apple steht vor allem für die Nichtberücksichtigung der arbeitsrechtlichen und gesundheitlichen Belangen der asiatischen Arbeiter in der Kritik. Des Weiteren gab es Vorfälle, bei denen Überstunden geschoben werden mussten und es zur Unterschreitung des gesetzlichen Mindestlohns kam. Eine Untersuchung von Apple widersprach dem, stellte jedoch Verstöße gegen den Apple-eigenen Verhaltenskodex für Zulieferer fest. Seit 2012 überwacht das Unternehmen die Wochenarbeitszeiten von mehr als einer Million Arbeitern bei Zulieferbetrieben und veröffentlicht diese Daten im Internet.</p>

 </div>
 <br><br>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
  <br>
  Website & Texte: <br>
  Carolin Körner&thinsp;&ensp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Julian Oste <br>
  Florian von der Heide&ensp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Sarah Ritter
  <br><br>
  </footer>
  <script>
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I link the script through

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

nothing happens when I scroll.

This is my css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 -moz-hyphens: none;
 -o-hyphens: none;
 -webkit-hyphens: none;
 -ms-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none;
 background-color: #C5F8FF;
 margin-left: -1vw;
 margin-right: -1vw;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
 text-align: center;
}

td {
 text-align: left;
}

.complogo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 1%;
 width: 5vw;
}

.unserLogo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 1%;
 width: 10vw;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #030303;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 7%;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.07em;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.navOpener {
    margin-left: 0.3%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#textbox {
    width:55%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    text-align: justify;
    /*Automatische Bindestriche*/
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 1vw;
        padding-right: 1vw;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
                background-color:  white;
}

.footer {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        color: #818181;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Where's your css ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltaaqcg2/1/

Comment: Be advised `position: sticky` is not supported by IE11.

Comment: Fortunately in this case that would simply mean the menu doesn't follow you in IE11. Worthy sacrifice to have a far simpler implementation considering how low IE11 is now in usage.

Comment: If my below answer helps you please click on gray "check" and gray up triangle on the left side of my answer

Comment: Your code is working just fine. (the styling however is causing your menu to be hidden beneath the content)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to set your navbar as `position: fixed`. This will position your navbar relative to the viewport (window).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```
#navbar {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

You will also likely need to adjust the `z-index` to be higher than the subsequent elements:

```
z-index: 10;
```

**UPDATE**

Consider refactoring your JavaScript a bit too. I would also recommend looking into *throttling* so that your script isn't adversely affecting page performance.

```
/* 
    IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) protects the global
    scope from the variables navbar and sticky and the toggleSticky function.
*/
(function () {
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function toggleSticky() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }

    /*
        Add event listener as opposed to overwriting any other scroll handlers.
        There is also no need to create an anoymous function to call your scroll
        handling function, simply pass the name of the handler:
    */
    window.addEventListener('scroll', toggleSticky);
}());
```

https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: thank you! that worked! now my image is placed under the navopener, guess I'll place it with position: absolute.

Comment: I guess you figured out whatever JavaScript issue you were having?